# How to build a photo grid with dynamic item width that fills the screen width?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following example of how the grid should look. Columns are set (in this case 2 but should be modifiable). Height should be the same for each row while photo width is dynamic and the photos fill the whole screen width:

[image]

I tried many things but I don't seem to be getting closer to the desired look.

1. I tried just using a `LazyVGrid` with flexible grid items, but it seems like it's made to work with square views, and trying to make it dynamic is pretty much impossible. The closest I could get was spannable views, which is not enough for the desired look:

```
 LazyVGrid(columns: gridColumns, alignment: .leading) {
                ForEach(viewModel.metadatas.chunked(into: gridColumns.count), id: \.self) { rowMetadatas in
                    ForEach(rowMetadatas, id: \.self) { metadata in
                        MediaCellView(metadata: metadata)
                            .frame(width: CGFloat(metadata.width == 0 ? 500 : metadata.width) * viewModel.getSize(rowMetadatas: rowMetadatas))
                    }
                }
            }
```

I also tried to calculate the ratio at which I could shrink the frame of each view to try and fit them based on the number of columns, but this also failed:

```
    func getSize(rowMetadatas: [tableMetadata]) -> CGFloat {
        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        var newSummedWidth: CGFloat = 0

        for metadata in rowMetadatas {
            let height1 = CGFloat(metadata.height == 0 ? 500 : metadata.height)
            let width1 = CGFloat(metadata.width == 0 ? 500 : metadata.width)

            let scaleFactor1 = (rowMetadatas.compactMap { CGFloat($0.height) }.max() ?? 0) / height1
            let newHeight1 = height1 * scaleFactor1
            let newWidth1 = width1 * scaleFactor1

            newSummedWidth += CGFloat(newWidth1)
        }

        let shrinkRatio: CGFloat = screenWidth / newSummedWidth

        return shrinkRatio
    }
```

2. I then decided to try this library: https://github.com/exyte/Grid which looked like it might help me achieve what I wanted, but sadly nothing worked.
3. Finally, I decided to use H and VStacks and I came the closest with this so far, but still not enough:

```
            StaggeredGrid(list: viewModel.metadatas, columns: 2, content: { metadata in
                MediaCellView(metadata: metadata)
            })
```

```
struct MediaCellView: View {
    let metadata: tableMetadata
    @StateObject private var viewModel = MediaCellViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: viewModel.thumbnail)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .onAppear {
                viewModel.configure(metadata: metadata)
                viewModel.downloadThumbnail()
            }
    }
}
```

```
var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: showIndicators) {
            HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(setUpList(), id: \.self) { columnData in
                    LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
                        ForEach(columnData, id: \.self) { object  in
                            content(object)
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            .padding(.vertical)
        }
    }
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

I think what I need is achievable with stacks, but without manual frame calculations it seems like it favors the height of the photos, instead of the width.

Is there a way to fix this?

Edit: By a suggestion I swapped the stacks, and sadly it still prefers to size the cells with the height first rather than the width...

```
LazyVStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(viewModel.metadatas.chunked(into: 2), id: \.self) { rowMetadatas in
                        HStack(spacing: 0) {
                            ForEach(rowMetadatas, id: \.self) { metadata in
                                MediaCellView(metadata: metadata)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

```
    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: viewModel.thumbnail)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .onAppear {
                viewModel.configure(metadata: metadata)
                viewModel.downloadThumbnail()
            }
    }
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: Looks like you're nearly there, but it seems you have your horizontal and vertical stacks mixed up. Shouldn't the outer stack be a ```LazyVStack``` (instead of ```HStack```) and the rows ```HStack``` (instead of ```LazyVStack```)?

Comment: @BenzyNeez I don't think so, because I need to have a set amount of columns, and for that HStack should be first.

Comment: You do that by organising the data. Your ```columnData``` should only contain two items.

Comment: @BenzyNeez I edited my post with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for trying out the suggestions in my comments.

I think you are getting closer, it is now just a matter of sorting out the scaling.

I am assuming that the sizes of the images are known. So here is an example of how to scale the items, using colors for demo purposes:

```swift
struct MetaData {
    let width: CGFloat
    let height: CGFloat
    let color: Color
}

struct ContentView: View {

    let item1 = MetaData(width: 200, height: 600, color: .orange)
    let item2 = MetaData(width: 450, height: 300, color: .blue)
    let item3 = MetaData(width: 100, height: 600, color: .green)
    let item4 = MetaData(width: 900, height: 200, color: .yellow)

    private func item(_ meta: MetaData, scalingFactor: CGFloat) -> some View {
        meta.color
            .frame(width: meta.width * scalingFactor, height: meta.height * scalingFactor)
    }

    private func aRow(_ meta1: MetaData, _ meta2: MetaData, fullWidth: CGFloat) -> some View {
        let maxHeight = max(meta1.height, meta2.height)
        var scaleFactor1 = maxHeight / meta1.height
        var scaleFactor2 = maxHeight / meta2.height
        let totalWidth = (meta1.width * scaleFactor1) + (meta2.width * scaleFactor2)
        scaleFactor1 *= fullWidth / totalWidth
        scaleFactor2 *= fullWidth / totalWidth
        return HStack(spacing: 0) {
            item(meta1, scalingFactor: scaleFactor1)
            item(meta2, scalingFactor: scaleFactor2)
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
                aRow(item1, item2, fullWidth: proxy.size.width)
                aRow(item3, item4, fullWidth: proxy.size.width)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: ScaledItems]

I hope this helps and you are able to adapt the logic for use in your code.

---

*EDIT* Another way to perform the layout is with a custom `Layout` implementation. This would have the advantage that the dimensions of the images would not necessarily need to be known prior to layout.

Here is a custom `Layout` that implements the logic that was being performed by the function `aRow` in the example above:

```swift
struct HStackEqualHeightFullWidth: Layout {

    private func preferredSize(subviews: Subviews, proposedWidth: CGFloat?) -> CGSize {
        let subviewDimensions = subviews.map { $0.dimensions(in: .unspecified) }
        let maxHeight: CGFloat = subviewDimensions.reduce(.zero) { currentMax, subviewSize in
            max(currentMax, subviewSize.height)
        }
        let totalWidth: CGFloat = subviewDimensions.reduce(.zero) { currentWidth, subviewSize in
            currentWidth + (subviewSize.width * (maxHeight / max(subviewSize.height, 1)))
        }
        let targetWidth = proposedWidth ?? totalWidth
        return CGSize(width: targetWidth, height: maxHeight * (targetWidth / max(totalWidth, 1)))
    }

    func sizeThatFits(
        proposal: ProposedViewSize,
        subviews: Subviews,
        cache: inout Void
    ) -> CGSize {
        return preferredSize(subviews: subviews, proposedWidth: proposal.width)
    }

    func placeSubviews(
        in bounds: CGRect,
        proposal: ProposedViewSize,
        subviews: Subviews,
        cache: inout Void
    ) {
        let height = preferredSize(subviews: subviews, proposedWidth: bounds.width).height
        var point = bounds.origin
        for subview in subviews {
            let dimensions = subview.dimensions(in: .unspecified)
            let scalingFactor = height / max(dimensions.height, 1)
            let scaledWidth = dimensions.width * scalingFactor
            let placementProposal = ProposedViewSize(width: scaledWidth, height: height)
            subview.place(at: point, proposal: placementProposal)
            point = CGPoint(x: point.x + scaledWidth, y: point.y)
        }
    }
}
```

This can be used in place of the `HStack` in the earlier example. So this now makes the main `body` much simpler:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    let item1 = MetaData(width: 200, height: 600, color: .orange)
    let item2 = MetaData(width: 450, height: 300, color: .blue)
    let item3 = MetaData(width: 100, height: 600, color: .green)
    let item4 = MetaData(width: 900, height: 200, color: .yellow)

    private func item(_ meta: MetaData) -> some View {
        meta.color
            .frame(idealWidth: meta.width, idealHeight: meta.height)
    }

    var body: some View {
        LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
            HStackEqualHeightFullWidth {
                item(item1)
                item(item2)
            }
            HStackEqualHeightFullWidth {
                item(item3)
                item(item4)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could try using the custom `Layout` in the same way in the `body` of your code. With luck it might solve your layout problem.

Comment: @MilenPivchev Answer updated with a custom ```Layout``` implementation. I'm hoping this will work for you too if you try plugging it into your code.